# \biboptions{authoryear} for documentclass {scrbook}

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am using the documentclass `scrbook` and want to cite so that it looks like this:

> Author(Year).

Is there a possibility to use `\biboptions{authoryear}` in `scrbook` or anything similar to it?

I use a template from my university and every time I try to change the documentclass to `elsarticle` I get an error. That's why I am looking for a solution with `scrbook`.

Thanks in advance.

code:

```
     \documentclass
    [paper=a4,      
    twoside=on,     
    DIV=13,         
    fontsize=12pt,  
    BCOR=15mm,  
    parskip=half,   
    numbers=noenddot,
    cleardoublepage=empty] 
    {scrbook} 
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib} 
\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\usepackage[]{acronym}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scrhack}
```

I want to use something like this:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{model2-names}
\biboptions{authoryear}
```

If I try to change the documentclass to elsarticle, the following error appears:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:462:
LaTeX Error:
 Command \bibhang already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.462 \newlength{\bibhang}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preamble code you load `biblatex`

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib} 
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
```

But then you want to use `natbib`

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{model2-names}
\biboptions{authoryear}
```

The two packages `biblatex` and `natbib` are incompatible since they use completely different approaches to bibliography and citation formatting.

The particular error

> ```
> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:462:
> LaTeX Error:
>  Command \bibhang already defined.
>                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.462 \newlength{\bibhang}
> ```

you quote happens if you load `biblatex` after you have already loaded `natbib`. Since the two packages are fundamentally incompatible, there are some definition clashes between the two, which is fine under the reasonable assumption that they are never loaded in the same document.

**Load either `biblatex` or `natbib` but not both.** You can find out more about `natbib` vs. `biblatex` at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864).

Comment: I was able to solve my problem, thank you for your help.